# How to not run out of memory when running python script forever

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, infinite-loop

I have a script that parses csv, removes old data and inserts new data into mongodb continuously inside a CentOS vm. I seem to run out of memory after few days and script crashes. How can I run it forever without this problem. Code looks like this:

```
def CSV_TO_MONGO:
    '''
    '''

import gc
while True:
    CSV_TO_MONGO()
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: You have some kind of mechanism to remove the data you're not using anymore? This sounds like you're trying to endlessly store data in a db without removing anything like ever.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention its deleting old data from mongodb and inserting new data from csv.

Comment: Everything else runs fine. I see memory getting released after the script crashes. Cant figure out how to make it run forever without loosing memory. Manual call to garbage collection doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing seems to to do the job. But unsure if its the best way.
For now this is working until a better solution comes up.

Edit: Discovered that mongodb is part of the problem. Doing bulk delete and bulk insert continuously takes toll on RAM.

```
def CSV_TO_MONGO:
    '''
    '''

from multiprocessing import Process
while True:
    p = Process(target=CSV_TO_MONGO)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```